# WPF-Component not visible

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have created a WPF form that contains a menu and three tabs. In the first tab I want to insert a combo box. The combo box should be defined in a separate UserControl. The program compiles. However, the combo box is not displayed. Can you give me an advice what could be the problem?
Here is the main form:

```
<Window x:Class="analyser.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:analyser"
        xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:analyser.Component"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- Define a style for TabItem -->
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" /> <!-- Set the desired font size (e.g., 16) -->
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <MenuItem Header="_File">
                    <MenuItem Header="_New"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="_Open"/>
                    <Separator />
                    <MenuItem Header="_Exit" />
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Help">
                    <MenuItem Header="_About"/>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>

            <TabControl>
                <TabItem Header="auswählen">
                    <!-- Content for Tab 1 -->
                    <uc:StockBox/>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Tab 2">
                    <!-- Content for Tab 2 -->
                    <TextBlock Text="This is Tab 2 content."/>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Tab 3">
                    <!-- Content for Tab 3 -->
                    <TextBlock Text="This is Tab 3 content."/>
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here the component:

```
<UserControl x:Class="analyser.Component.StockBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:analyser.Component"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="300">
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel>
                <ComboBox Width="150" SelectedIndex="0">
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Option 1"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Option 2"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Option 3"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Option 4"/>
                </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
      
</UserControl>
```

Comment: This code works for me. I literally copy&pasted your snippets and they work fine. Could it be that your `Stockbox.xaml` does not have a corresponding `Stockbox.xaml.cs` file? If that file is missing the control is not displayed.